# Enviar la informacion que se encuentra en un table row de una tabla a un modal

Tags: html, jquery

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que en el momento en el que se le da click al boton Eliminar Producto

La informacion que se encuentra en este tr se mande al siguiente modal, para asi poder modificar la informacion de esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que se encuentra en el controlador

```
$.ajax({
        url:"ajax/api.php?accion=obtener-lista-inventario-productos",
        method:"GET",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(respuesta){
            console.log(respuesta);
            for(var i=0;i<respuesta.length;i++){
                $('#table-inventario-producto').append(
                    '<tr>'+
                    '<td><span id="nombreProducto">'+respuesta[i].nombre+'</span></td>'+
                    '<td class="text-center"><span id="fechaElaboracion">'+respuesta[i].fechaElaboracion+'</span></td>'+
                    '<td class="text-center"><span id="fechaVencimiento">'+respuesta[i].fechaVencimiento+'</span></td>'+
                    '<td class="text-center"><span id="cantidadBandejas">'+respuesta[i].cantidadBandejas+'</span></td>'+
                    '<td><button id="btn-eliminar-producto-'+respuesta[i].idinventario_Producto+'" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEliminarProducto" class="btn btn-link btn-sm">Eliminar Producto</button></td>'+
                    '</tr>'
                );   

                 $('#btn-eliminar-producto-'+respuesta[i].idinventario_Producto+'').click(function(){

                });
                }


        },
        error:function(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
```

Y este es el codigo del modal a donde quiero que vaya la informacion del tr:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalEliminarProducto" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Eliminar Producto</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
              <form class="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Producto:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt-producto" disabled>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Fecha de Elaboracion:</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="txt-fecha-elaboracion" disabled>
              </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Fecha Vencimiento:</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="txt-fecha-vencimiento" disabled>
                </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Cantidad:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txt-cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad">
              </div>
              </form>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-eliminar-producto-inventario">Eliminar Producto</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


    </div>

</div>
```

Esto es mas que todo para poder modificar la cantidad de producto que hay en el inventario, por eso los demas campos (Producto, fechaElaboracion y fechaVencimiento) están inhabilitados

Comment: puedes poner el código que abre la modal?

Comment: Tengo dos apreciaciones al respecto: **1-** Si vas a actualizar solo un valor _en tu caso la cantidad de producto_, podrías hacerlo desde la tabla a través de `ajax`, sin abrir un modal para ello. **2-** La actualización del inventario debe ser automática, cuando sale un producto _por que se vendió o se usó, por ejemplo_ debe reducir esa cantidad del stock automáticamente y al adquirir nuevas unidades de ese producto _por compra o devolución_, debería aumentar el stock también de manera automática.

Comment: @ajuni880 este codigo se encuentra dentro del ajax

Comment: @DjCrazy como podria hacer la idea que usted me recomienda en la opcion 1?

Con respecto al 2, en este caso lo que se realizar es eliminar el producto del inventario, no porque este se haya vendido, si no porque este se ha dañado y es imposible poder venderlo

Comment: Una cosa adicional, cuando estás creando el botón, le estás dando un `id` dentro del bucle, lo cual te puede generar un error ya que el atributo `id` debe ser único dentro del DOM, _es decir que dos botones no deben tener el mismo `id`_

Comment: @DjCrazy con respecto a lo del boton, eso ya lo habia tomado en cuenta, por lo cual añadi `btn-eliminar-producto-'+respuesta[i].idinventario_Producto+'`, asi se podra diferencia cada boton, ya que cada boton tendra el id del idinventario_Producto respectivo

Comment: Bien, respecto a tu comentario, la opción 1 se puede lograr mediante `ajax` capturando el identificador del producto y actualizando su stock al cambiar el valor del `input`. No es muy aconsejable, ya que el usuario se puede equivocar al ingresar el dato manual y tu módulo de inventario perdería veracidad. Si el producto es perecedero o se daña, deberías pensar en otro módulo para dar de baja estos productos... _pero ya me estoy saliendo demasiado de contexto_. Consulta un poco sobre `ajax` y haz pruebas y si tienes alguna dificultad, regresas aquí para preguntar de nuevo.

Comment: De hecho, veo que ya usas `ajax`. Perdón, no lo tuve en cuenta

Comment: @DjCrazy tranquilo no te preocupes.

Answer (score 0):

Como comentan en los comentarios no es buena practica coger datos de html y pasarlos al backend ya que el usuario tiene acceso al html y lo puede manipular. Deberías pasar el id del producto al backend y luego hacer la lógica de negocio ahí.

Pero aquí te dejo una solución que el propio [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) documenta.

He creado un atributo `data-prodcut` que tiene como valor el objeto `product` como `string`. Y luego cuando se abre la modal pues hago un get del atributo del botón y lo paso objeto js.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax/api.php?accion=obtener-lista-inventario-productos",
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (respuesta) {
    console.log(respuesta);
    for (var i = 0; i < respuesta.length; i++) {
      $("#table-inventario-producto").append(
            '<tr>' +
            '<td><span id="nombreProducto">' + respuesta[i].nombre + '</span></td>' +
            '<td class="text-center"><span id="fechaElaboracion">' + respuesta[i].fechaElaboracion + '</span></td>' +
            '<td class="text-center"><span id="fechaVencimiento">' + respuesta[i].fechaVencimiento + '</span></td>' +
            '<td class="text-center"><span id="cantidadBandejas">' + respuesta[i].cantidadBandejas + '</span></td>' +
            '<td><button id="btn-eliminar-producto-' + respuesta[i].idinventario_Producto + 
            '" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEliminarProducto" data-product='+ JSON.stringify(respuesta[i]) + ' class="btn btn-link btn-sm">Eliminar Producto</button></td>' +
            '</tr>'
        );

    }

     $("#modalEliminarProducto").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
        var product = button.data('product');
        var modal = $(this);
        // solo he puesto el campo de cantidad de ejemplo
        // tu puedes añadir los campos que faltan
        modal.find('#txt-cantidad').val(product.cantidadBandejas);
      });

  },
  error: function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  },
});
```

Comment: Intente realizar esta solucion y me aparecio el siguiente error 'Uncaught TypeError: button.data is not a function'

Comment: perdón me deje de pasar el `relatedTarget` a objeto jquery. He actualizado la respuesta prueba ahora.

Comment: Ahora me aparece el siguiente error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse'

Comment: prueba porfa era probelam de comillas

Comment: Aun nada amigo, sigue apareciéndome el mismo error, dice que es en la linea donde se encuentra `var product = JSON.parse(button.data('product'))`

Comment: he editado el codigo prueba ahora es debido a las comillas quiza me dejé algunas

Comment: Aun nada amigo, aparentemente es un error con el JSON.parse

Comment: pues no entiendo puedes probar de hacer un `console.log(button.data('product'))` a ver que te da

Comment: Lo realice y me aparece lo siguiente: `{"idinventario_Producto":"1","cantidadBandejas":"50","fechaElaboracion":"2020-03-14","fechaVencimiento":"2020-05-31","Productos_idProductos":"765","nombre":"Bandeja de Espumillitas"}`

Comment: pues JOSN.parse debería funcionar no entiendo la verdad. Prueba `var product = button.data('product')`

Comment: Tambien lo he intentado, al final no me aparece ningun error, pero al momento de ver el modal, la informacion no se imprime en el campo de cantidad

Comment: prueba con el código que hay dejando el `JSON.parse` sino va pues lo siento

Comment: Lo probe y nada amigo, muchas gracias por intentar ayudarme

Comment: prueba ahora la ultima vez es que con el copy-paste..

Comment: Aun nada amigo, muchas gracias

Comment: he actualizado el codigo y he hecho un fiddle ahora debería funcionarte. https://jsfiddle.net/hawks1/o4nLq2je/2/

Comment: Aun nada amigo, no se porque sera la vdd